# cuSolver Sparse solver fails with CUSOLVER_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR

Tags: cuda

I'm endeavouring to use cuSolver to solve a sparse linear system.

But when I run my code, it fails with `CUSOLVER_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR`.

What's going wrong? How does one debug this error?

My MWE follows and uses two data files (chosen somewhat arbitrarily):

- [mat65k.mtx](https://github.com/viennacl/viennacl-dev/blob/master/examples/testdata/mat65k.mtx) - Manually remove the lines beginning with `%`
- [rhs65025.txt](https://github.com/viennacl/viennacl-dev/blob/master/examples/testdata/rhs65025.txt)

## Code

````cpp
// Compile with: nvcc src/cuda_solver.cu -lcusolver -lcusparse

#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>

#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cusolverSp.h>
#include <cusparse.h>
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Sparse>

#define CUSOLVER_CHECK(err) (HandlecusolverError(err, __FILE__, __LINE__))
#define CUDA_CHECK(err) (HandleError(err, __FILE__, __LINE__))

static void HandlecusolverError(cusolverStatus_t err, const char* file, int line) {
  if (err != CUSOLVER_STATUS_SUCCESS) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: %d in %s at line %d, (error-code %d)\n", err, file, line, err);
    fflush(stdout);
    exit(-1);
  }
}

static void HandleError(cudaError_t err, const char* file, int line) {
  if (err != cudaSuccess) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: %s in %s at line %d (error-code %d)\n", cudaGetErrorString(err), file, line, err);
    fflush(stdout);
    exit(-1);
  }
}

#define CUSPARSE_CHECK(func)                                                         \
  {                                                                                  \
    cusparseStatus_t status = (func);                                                \
    if (status != CUSPARSE_STATUS_SUCCESS) {                                         \
      std::cerr << "Got cusparse error"                                              \
                << " at line: " << __LINE__ << " of file " << __FILE__ << std::endl; \
    }                                                                                \
  }

struct SparseSolverCUDA {
 private:
  cusolverSpHandle_t cusolver_handle = nullptr;
  csrqrInfo_t info                   = nullptr;
  cusparseMatDescr_t matrix_desc     = nullptr;
  cudaStream_t stream                = nullptr;
  const int32_t width                = 0;

  // We wish to solve the sparse linear system Ax=b where A is in CSR form
  double* d_csr_val_A    = nullptr;  // Values of the A matrix
  int32_t* d_csr_row_ptr = nullptr;  // Rows of the A matrix
  int32_t* d_csr_col_idx = nullptr;  // Columns of the A matrix
  double* d_b            = nullptr;  // Values of the b vector
  double* d_x            = nullptr;  // Values of the x vector

 public:
  using eigen_spmat_t = Eigen::SparseMatrix<double, Eigen::RowMajor, int32_t>;

  SparseSolverCUDA(const eigen_spmat_t& eigen_spmat) : width(width) {
    if (eigen_spmat.rows() != eigen_spmat.cols()) {
      throw std::runtime_error("SparseSolverCUDA matrix must be symmetric.");
    }

    // step 2: create cusolver handle, qr info and matrix descriptor
    CUSOLVER_CHECK(cusolverSpCreate(&cusolver_handle));

    CUDA_CHECK(cudaStreamCreateWithFlags(&stream, cudaStreamNonBlocking));
    CUSOLVER_CHECK(cusolverSpSetStream(cusolver_handle, stream));

    CUSPARSE_CHECK(cusparseCreateMatDescr(&matrix_desc));

    // Options:
    //   CUSPARSE_MATRIX_TYPE_GENERAL
    //   CUSPARSE_MATRIX_TYPE_SYMMETRIC
    //   CUSPARSE_MATRIX_TYPE_HERMITIAN
    //   CUSPARSE_MATRIX_TYPE_TRIANGULAR
    CUSPARSE_CHECK(cusparseSetMatType(matrix_desc, CUSPARSE_MATRIX_TYPE_GENERAL));
    // CUSPARSE_INDEX_BASE_ZERO and CUSPARSE_INDEX_BASE_ONE
    CUSPARSE_CHECK(cusparseSetMatIndexBase(matrix_desc, CUSPARSE_INDEX_BASE_ZERO));

    CUSOLVER_CHECK(cusolverSpCreateCsrqrInfo(&info));

    CUDA_CHECK(cudaMalloc(reinterpret_cast<void**>(&d_csr_val_A), eigen_spmat.nonZeros() * sizeof(double)));
    CUDA_CHECK(cudaMalloc(reinterpret_cast<void**>(&d_csr_row_ptr), eigen_spmat.outerSize() * sizeof(int32_t)));
    CUDA_CHECK(cudaMalloc(reinterpret_cast<void**>(&d_csr_col_idx), eigen_spmat.innerSize() * sizeof(int32_t)));
    CUDA_CHECK(cudaMalloc(reinterpret_cast<void**>(&d_b), eigen_spmat.rows() * sizeof(double)));
    CUDA_CHECK(cudaMalloc(reinterpret_cast<void**>(&d_x), eigen_spmat.rows() * sizeof(double)));
  }

  ~SparseSolverCUDA() {
    CUDA_CHECK(cudaFree(d_csr_row_ptr));
    CUDA_CHECK(cudaFree(d_csr_col_idx));
    CUDA_CHECK(cudaFree(d_csr_val_A));
    CUDA_CHECK(cudaFree(d_b));
    CUDA_CHECK(cudaFree(d_x));
    CUDA_CHECK(cudaStreamDestroy(stream));
    CUSPARSE_CHECK(cusparseDestroyMatDescr(matrix_desc));
    CUSOLVER_CHECK(cusolverSpDestroy(cusolver_handle));
  }

  void operator()(const eigen_spmat_t& A, const Eigen::VectorXd& b, std::vector<double>& x_out) const {
    // step 3: copy Aj and bj to device

    assert(A.rows() == b.size());
    assert(A.rows() == x_out.size());

    std::cerr << "type = " << typeid(A.innerIndexPtr()).name() << std::endl;

    CUDA_CHECK(
        cudaMemcpyAsync(d_csr_val_A, A.valuePtr(), A.nonZeros() * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, stream));
    CUDA_CHECK(cudaMemcpyAsync(
        d_csr_col_idx, A.innerIndexPtr(), A.innerSize() * sizeof(int32_t), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, stream));
    CUDA_CHECK(cudaMemcpyAsync(
        d_csr_row_ptr, A.outerIndexPtr(), A.outerSize() * sizeof(int32_t), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, stream));

    CUDA_CHECK(cudaMemcpyAsync(d_b, b.data(), A.rows() * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, stream));

    std::cerr << "A.rows() = " << A.rows() << std::endl;
    std::cerr << "A.nonZeros() = " << A.nonZeros() << std::endl;

    CUDA_CHECK(cudaStreamSynchronize(stream));

    int32_t singularity;
    const auto sparse_ret_code = cusolverSpDcsrlsvqr(
        cusolver_handle,
        A.rows(),
        A.nonZeros(),
        matrix_desc,
        d_csr_val_A,
        d_csr_row_ptr,
        d_csr_col_idx,
        d_b,
        0.0001,  // tol
        0,       // No ordering if reorder=0. Otherwise, symrcm, symamd, or csrmetisnd is used to reduce zero fill-in
        d_x,
        &singularity);

    if (sparse_ret_code != CUSOLVER_STATUS_SUCCESS) {
      std::string error_code_str;
      switch (sparse_ret_code) {
        case CUSOLVER_STATUS_SUCCESS:
          error_code_str = "The operation completed successfully.";
          break;
        case CUSOLVER_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED:
          error_code_str = "The library was not initialized.";
          break;
        case CUSOLVER_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED:
          error_code_str = "The resources could not be allocated.";
          break;
        case CUSOLVER_STATUS_INVALID_VALUE:
          error_code_str =
              "Invalid parameters were passed (m,nnz<=0, base index is not 0 or 1, reorder is not 0,1,2,3)";
          break;
        case CUSOLVER_STATUS_ARCH_MISMATCH:
          error_code_str = "The device only supports compute capability 2.0 and above.";
          break;
        case CUSOLVER_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR:
          error_code_str = "An internal operation failed.";
          break;
        case CUSOLVER_STATUS_MATRIX_TYPE_NOT_SUPPORTED:
          error_code_str = "The matrix type is not supported.";
          break;
      }

      throw std::runtime_error("Sparse solver failed with " + std::to_string(sparse_ret_code) + " " + error_code_str);
    }

    std::cerr << "Singularity = " << singularity << std::endl;

    CUDA_CHECK(cudaMemcpyAsync(x_out.data(), d_x, A.rows() * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost, stream));

    CUDA_CHECK(cudaStreamSynchronize(stream));
  }
};

int main() {
  CUDA_CHECK(cudaSetDevice(0));

  int width, height, nnz;
  std::ifstream fin("mat65k.mtx.txt");
  fin >> width >> height >> nnz;

  std::cerr << "Populating matrix A" << std::endl;

  std::cerr << "nnz = " << nnz << std::endl;

  std::vector<Eigen::Triplet<double>> triples;
  triples.reserve(nnz);
  for (int i = 0; i < nnz; i++) {
    int row, col;
    double val;
    fin >> row >> col >> val;
    triples.emplace_back(row, col, val);
  }

  Eigen::SparseMatrix<double, Eigen::RowMajor> mat(height, width);
  mat.setFromTriplets(triples.begin(), triples.end());

  std::cerr << "rows = " << mat.rows() << std::endl;
  std::cerr << "cols = " << mat.cols() << std::endl;
  std::cerr << "nnz = " << mat.nonZeros() << std::endl;
  std::cerr << "mat.innerSize() = " << mat.innerSize() << std::endl;
  std::cerr << "mat.outerSize() = " << mat.outerSize() << std::endl;

  fin.close();

  std::cerr << "Populating RHS" << std::endl;
  fin.open("rhs65025.txt");
  Eigen::VectorXd b(width);
  for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    double val;
    fin >> val;
    b(i) = val;
  }

  std::cerr << "Compressing matrix A" << std::endl;
  mat.makeCompressed();

  auto ssc = SparseSolverCUDA(mat);

  std::vector<double> x(width);
  ssc(mat, b, x);

  return 0;
}
```
````